# SML/NJ fail to override a function in other modules

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to override `print` to let it output to outstreams other than `stdout`. I have two files: `m1.sml` and `main.sml` in the same directory. I want to override the behavior of `print` in both files but it fails to override the `print` inside `m1.sml`.

**m1.sml**

```
structure Demo : sig
  val printSomething : string -> unit
  end = 
  struct
    fun printSomething s = print s
  end
```

**main.sml**

```
use "m1.sml";

fun redirectPrint strm str = TextIO.output (strm, str);

fun testing output = 
  let 
      val outStrm = TextIO.openOut output
      val print = redirectPrint outStrm 
  in
    (print "This will show up in test.txt\n"; 
     Demo.printSomething "This won't show up in test.txt\n"; 
     TextIO.closeOut outStrm)
  end;

testing "test.txt"
```

Running `sml main.sml` will yield

```
...
[autoloading done]
val redirectPrint = fn : TextIO.outstream -> TextIO.vector -> unit
val testing = fn : string -> unit
this won't show up in test.txt
val it = () : unit
```

---

As you have seen in the output, it works for the line

```
print "This will show up in test.txt\n" (written to test.txt)
```

but not the next line

```
Demo.printSomething "This won't show up in test.txt\n"; (printed to stdout)
```

which just prints to `stdout`.

`Demo.printSomething`, however, also calls `print`. Also, in the current scope where `Demo.printSomething` is called, `print` was overridden.

I wonder why this happens?

Comment: Isn't that just because `print` is a local variable in `testing` and local variables aren't visible in other functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because identifiers in ML are [lexically scoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping), as in all modern programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder why this happens?

Because of order. `Demo.printSomething` refers to the old `print`. As you rebind `print` in a local scope later, `Demo.printSomething` does not change its definition. A simpler example of this:

```
- val y = 42;
> val y = 42 : int
- fun f () = y;
> val f = fn : unit -> int
- val y = 43;
> val y = 43 : int
- f ();
> val it = 42 : int
```

One way that doesn't seem to work could have been to `;use "m1.sml";` in the local scope after your redefinition. Another way could be to parameterise your `Demo` module with the desired `print`:

```
functor Demo (P : sig val print : string -> unit end) =
struct
  val printSomething = P.print
end
```

and then apply it in your local scope with the revised print function:

```
;use "m2.sml";

fun curry f x y = f (x, y)

fun testing output =
    let
      val outStrm = TextIO.openOut output
      val print = curry TextIO.output outStrm
      structure ThisDemo = Demo(struct val print = print end)
    in print "foo\n"
     ; ThisDemo.printSomething "bar\n"
     ; TextIO.closeOut outStrm
    end;

val _ = testing "test.txt"
```

Of course, if that's all `Demo` does, it's a little silly, but if it also does other things, having it parameterize its side-effectful components is quite meaningful, since it means you can better test the module by mocking those.

**Edit:** Applying that functor locally doesn't seem to be part of the definition of Standard ML, so it only works in Moscow ML. (I think this has to do with mixing parametric polymorphism of functions and modules.) I'm not sure if there's a prettier way than also wrapping `testing` in a module.